# Python string replace different results for two similar words

Tags: python, string

I have a long string to replace() functions in one of my methods. I am changing one piece of the string based off of a simple replace. Here's an example since I have trouble putting this into words.

```
.replace('abc', 'new_code_abc').replace('cm_abc', 'new_code_cm_abc')
```

The problem is abc is in both versions of the result so only the first replace is ever being done.

How can I rewrite these replaces so that if the string is abc and ONLY abc it prints out new_code_abc?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this if statement should work for you.

```
if "cm_abc" in variable:
    variable = variable.replace('cm_abc', 'new_code_cm_abc')
else:
    variable = variable.replace('abc', 'new_code_abc')
```